# Error: Type PdfViewerComponent in node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/ng2-pdf-viewer.d.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, pdf-viewer

I got this error when trying `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`, using `ionic serve` or `ionic cordova run android` the app works good.

> Error: Type PdfViewerComponent in C:/app/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/ng2-pdf-viewer.d.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: PdfViewerModule in C:/app/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/ng2-pdf-viewer.d.ts and PdfModalPageModule in C:/app/src/pages/document-pdf/document-pdf.module.ts! Please consider moving PdfViewerComponent in C:/app/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/ng2-pdf-viewer.d.ts to a higher module that imports PdfViewerModule in C:/app/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/ng2-pdf-viewer.d.ts and PdfModalPageModule in C:/app/src/pages/document-pdf/document-pdf.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes PdfViewerComponent in C:/app/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/ng2-pdf-viewer.d.ts then import that NgModule in PdfViewerModule in C:/app/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/ng2-pdf-viewer.d.ts and PdfModalPageModule in C:/app/src/pages/document-pdf/document-pdf.module.ts.

I only import ng-pdf-viewer in `document-pdf.module.ts` not in app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPageModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {PdfModalPage} from "./document-pdf";
import {PdfViewerComponent} from "ng2-pdf-viewer";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [PdfModalPage, PdfViewerComponent],
    imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(PdfModalPage)],
})
export class PdfModalPageModule {}
```

angular & ionic version

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/contacts": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/file": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/media": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/media-capture": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/sim": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/video-editor": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/video-player": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic/pro": "^1.0.16",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angular2-moment": "1.7.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "2.6.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "com-badrit-base64": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "^6.4.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "^0.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-contacts": "^2.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^0.1.25",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^1.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-sim": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-video-editor": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^3.9.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^4.9.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic2-auto-complete": "1.6.2-alpha",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "4.1.0",
    "ng2-timeago": "1.0.7",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.2.5",
    "rxjs": "5.5.5",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.8",
    "ionic": "3.19.1",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  },
  "config": {},
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media": {},
      "cordova-plugin-contacts": {},
      "cordova-plugin-sim": {},
      "com-badrit-base64": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-video-editor": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {}
    }
  }
}
```

ionic info

```
cli packages: (C:\app\node_modules)
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

I tried with a fresh install deleting /platforms /www /plugins and /node_modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import the `PdfViewerModule` in your `document-pdf.module.ts`, and do not declare the `PdfViewerComponent` in there, as it is already declared in the `PdfViewerModule`.

Update: this is how your module should look like:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPageModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {PdfModalPage} from "./document-pdf";
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [PdfModalPage],
    imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(PdfModalPage), PdfViewerModule]
})
export class PdfModalPageModule {}
```

Comment: If I delete `, PdfViewerComponent` from the `declarations:` I get this error:
 `Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known property of 'pdf-viewer'.`

Comment: Edited the orignal answer to include how your module should look like. This is definitely a change that should be made. If it still fails after that, then something is up with Ionic that I don't know unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, I was importing `PdfViewerComponent` instead of `PdfViewerModule`